# Disable Popup Form Many2many field in Odoo

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, odoo-12

How to disable the popup adding form when adding a new line in many2many field tree view? Everytime I add a line, it always open a popup form, I just want to add a line directly in tree view only.

I've tried editable="bottom" and editable="top" in tree view but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with following option:

```
widget="many2many_tags"
```

For example:

```
<field name="many2many_field_name"
       widget="many2many_tags" 
       options="{'color_field': 'color', 'no_create_edit': True}"
       placeholder="XYZ..."/>
```

**EDIT**

For the tree view:

```
widget="one2many_list"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I add widget="one2many_list" in field and it works. I'm adding the widget in tree view and not in the field earlier so that's why it's not working. Thank you again.

Comment: Cool. I edit it in the answer.